# Periodicity of random walks on groups

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Periodicity occurs in random walks on groups when the entire support of the increment distribution falls into a single coset of some subgroup. Explain?

Comment: Please explain which part you don't understand.  Do you know the definitions of all the terms in this sentence?

Comment: Yes I understood the question, but can't show that support falls into a coset of some subgroup.